# Number of ways to partition a number in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion, data-partitioning

I have defined a recursive function that takes a number, `n`, and returns a `list` of lists of the numbers that sum to that number (partitions):

```
def P(n):
    # base case of recursion: zero is the sum of the empty list
    if n == 0:
        yield []
        return

    for p in P(n-1):        
        p.append(1)
        yield p
        p.pop()
        if p and (len(p) < 2 or p[-2] > p[-1]):
            p[-1] += 1
            yield p
```

I was wondering how to make the function return the *number* of partitions for number `n`.

For example, `P(6)` would return `10`.

Comment: P(6) would return 11 not 10. Your own function returns 11 partitions.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the "Partition function formulas" section of the [Partiton (number theory)](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) page on Wikipedia, you'll see that there isn't a *simple* way to find the partition number.

Instead, your best bet is probably:

```
sum(1 for _ in P(6))
```

or, slightly simpler but memory hogging for large numbers

```
len(list(P(6)))
```

using your existing function.

Also note if you want to be able to save the values returned by `P`, you should be `yield`ing `p[:]` not `p` -- you want to make a copy, not yield the same list (which you change) over and over. You can see why if you do `list(P(6))` -- it returns a list of *the same empty list repeated over and over*.

Fore more info about partitioning, see [Partitioning with Python](http://wordaligned.org/articles/partitioning-with-python).

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html):

> P(n, k) denotes the number of ways of writing n as a sum of exactly k
> terms or, equivalently, the number of partitions into parts of which
> the largest is exactly k. (Note that if "exactly k" is changed to "k
> or fewer" and "largest is exactly k," is changed to "no element
> greater than k," then the partition function q is obtained.) For
> example, P(5, 3) = 2, since the partitions of 5 of length 3 are {3, 1, 1}
> and {2, 2, 1}, and the partitions of 5 with maximum element 3 are {3, 2}
> and {3, 1, 1}. 
> ... 
> P(n, k) can be computed from the recurrence relation
> **P(n, k) = P(n-1, k-1) + P(n-k, k)**
> (Skiena 1990, p. 58; Ruskey) with **P(n, k) = 0 for k > n, P(n, n) = 1, and
> P(n, 0) = 0.**

So if we want to calculate the number of ways of writing n as a sum, we should calculate-

[image]

Let's define P(n, k):

```py
def p(n, k):
    """Gives the number of ways of writing n as a sum of exactly k terms or, equivalently, 
    the number of partitions into parts of which the largest is exactly k.  
    """
    if n < k:
        return 0
    if n == k:
        return 1
    if k == 0:
        return 0

    return p(n-1, k-1) + p(n-k, k)
```

Now we can calculate the number of ways of writing `n` as a sum:

```py
n = 6
partitions_count = 0

for k in range(n + 1):
    partitions_count += p(n, k)

print(partitions_count)

# Output:
# 11
```

As `p(n, k)` is a recursive function, you can boost the speed by saving values of each `p(n, k)` in a dictionary (thanks to [the fast hash-based search](https://realpython.com/binary-search-python/#hash-based-search)!) and check if we have calculated the value (check if the value is in the dictionary) before calculating:

```py
dic = {}
def p(n, k):
    """Gives the number of ways of writing n as a sum of exactly k terms or, equivalently, 
        the number of partitions into parts of which the largest is exactly k.  
    """
    if n < k:
        return 0
    if n == k:
        return 1
    if k == 0:
        return 0

    key = str(n) + ',' + str(k)
    try:
        temp = dic[key]
    except:
        temp = p(n-1, k-1) + p(n-k, k)
        dic[key] = temp
    finally:
        return temp
```

Full function:

```py
def partitions_count(n):
    """Gives the number of ways of writing the integer n as a sum of positive integers,
    where the order of addends is not considered significant.
    """
    dic = {}
    def p(n, k):
        """Gives the number of ways of writing n as a sum of exactly k terms or, equivalently, 
        the number of partitions into parts of which the largest is exactly k.  
        """
        if n < k:
            return 0
        if n == k:
            return 1
        if k == 0:
            return 0
        
        key = str(n) + ',' + str(k)
        try:
            temp = dic[key]
        except:
            temp = p(n-1, k-1) + p(n-k, k)
            dic[key] = temp
        finally:
            return temp
    
    partitions_count = 0
    for k in range(n + 1):
        partitions_count += p(n, k)
    return partitions_count
```

Helpful links:

- [Partitions - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjCIq58rZ8I&list=LLxK8YeFWkWA2Qb2Lcs7qvjQ)
- [Partiton (number theory)](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example in Java for computing your desired result.

```
/**
 * Returns the number of ways the number n can be partitioned
 * into sums of positive integers larger than k. 
 * @param k
 * @param n
 * @return
 */
public static long partition(long k, long n){
    long sum = 0;
    if(k > n) return 0;
    if(k == n) return 1;
    sum += partition(k+1, n) + partition(k, n-k);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: -1 as the OP asked for `python`. So even if the answer may be good, it is on the wrong place.

Comment: @bmu You're right, but this code is really easy for most of python users to understand. And I think the question is somehow about the algorithm. Take a look at [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271207/how-should-we-handle-answers-in-a-programming-language-other-than-what-the-op-re). I think the down vote should be for lack of explanation.