# Number Partitioning: non-recursive algorithm with determinate loops only

Tags: algorithm, numbers, partitioning

I am trying to generate the [number partition set of a non-negative integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). There are several solutions, also on this site, like in [Number of ways to partition a number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7802160/5459839):

> ```py
> def P(n):
>     # base case of recursion: zero is the sum of the empty list
>     if n == 0:
>         yield []
>         return
>
>     for p in P(n-1):        
>         p.append(1)
>         yield p
>         p.pop()
>         if p and (len(p) < 2 or p[-2] > p[-1]):
>             p[-1] += 1
>             yield p
> ```

But these solutions use recursion or indeterminate loops (do-while loops).

I want to do this with an *iterative* solution where all loops are "determinate" (iteration a number of times that is known when the loop starts). But I don't see how this can be done. Is this even possible, given that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function) says "No closed-form expression for the partition function is known"?

Comment: You can change an indeterminate loop to a determinate one with a counter pretty easily.

Comment: The counters are isolated. The code is inside MPI function call.

Comment: What is the number partition set of an integer? Can you give an input/output example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)
"In number theory and combinatorics, a partition of a non-negative integer n, also called an integer partition, is a way of writing n as a sum of positive integers. Two sums that differ only in the order of their summands are considered the same partition. (If order matters, the sum becomes a composition.) For example, 4 can be partitioned in five distinct ways:

4
3 + 1

2 + 2
2 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1

Answer (score 2):

Below I provide a function in Python that only uses "definite" `for` loops, i.e. loops which iterate over a range that is known before the loop starts.

It makes use of the recurrence relation mentioned at [Wikipedia - Triangle of partition numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_of_partition_numbers#Recurrence_relation):

> ...each partition of  into  pieces, counted by (), can be formed either by adding a piece of size one to a partition of −1 into −1 pieces, counted by <sub>−1</sub>(−1), or by increasing by one each piece in a partition of − into  pieces, counted by (−).

```py
def make_partitions(n):
    # all numbers up to n, represented as a partition with just one member
    dp = [[[total]] for total in range(0, n + 1)]
    dp[0] = []
    # the last of these is one possible partition of n:
    result = dp[-1][:]

    # for increasing size of the partitions (i.e. count of terms)
    for size in range(2, n + 1):
        prev = dp[size - 1]
        dp[size - 1] = []
        # generate partitions using already known partitions
        for total in range(size, n + 1):
            prev, dp[total] = dp[total], (
                [partition + [1] for partition in prev] + 
                [
                    [val+1 for val in partition]
                    for partition in dp[total-size]
                ]
            )
        result.extend(dp[-1])
    return result
```

For instance, the call `make_partitions(9)` will return this list:

```
[
    [9],
    [8, 1],
    [7, 2],
    [6, 3],
    [5, 4],
    [7, 1, 1],
    [6, 2, 1],
    [5, 3, 1],
    [4, 4, 1],
    [5, 2, 2],
    [4, 3, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [6, 1, 1, 1],
    [5, 2, 1, 1],
    [4, 3, 1, 1],
    [4, 2, 2, 1],
    [3, 3, 2, 1],
    [3, 2, 2, 2],
    [5, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [4, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    [3, 3, 1, 1, 1],
    [3, 2, 2, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]
```